# ExecutorService inside another ExecutorService in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a use case wherein I have two Tasks( both makes a db call to execute a function), each of these two tasks further have muntiple concurrent tasks to be performed (each of these muntiple tasks also make a db call to execute another function).

It is like :

Task1 : calls fn1 in DB,
based on some condition parallely invoke n tasks to call fn2 in DB.

Task2 : calls fn3 in DB,
based on some condition parallely invoke n tasks to call fn4 in DB.

Task1 & Task2 are also executed parallely.

I used ExecutorService interface and newFixedThreadPool of size 2 to invoke Task1 and Task2, inside Runnable class of Task1 & Task2 I created another Executors with newFixedThreadPool of size n.

Is it the right approach to proceed? Any suggestion or resources are welcomed.

```
package java_codes;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        ExecutorService executor= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        
        executor.execute(new MyRunnable(1));
        executor.execute(new MyRunnable(2));
        
        executor.shutdown();
        
        while(!executor.isTerminated()) {
            // continue untill all oprn are done
        }

    }

}
```

```
package java_codes;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    
    private Integer indx=0;
    
    MyRunnable(Integer indx){
        this.indx=indx;
    }
    

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Inside Indx="+indx+" Outer thread"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        
        ExecutorService executor= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            executor.execute(new MySecondRunnable(indx*100+i)); 
        }
        
        executor.shutdown();
        
        while(!executor.isTerminated()) {
            // continue untill all oprn are done
        }
    }

}
```

```
package java_codes;

public class MySecondRunnable implements Runnable {

    private Integer indx=0;
    
    MySecondRunnable(Integer indx){
        this.indx=indx;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Inside Indx="+indx+" Inner thread"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

}
```

Below is the output:

```
Inside Indx=2 Outer threadpool-1-thread-2
Inside Indx=1 Outer threadpool-1-thread-1
Inside Indx=200 Inner threadpool-2-thread-1
Inside Indx=100 Inner threadpool-3-thread-1
Inside Indx=101 Inner threadpool-3-thread-2
Inside Indx=201 Inner threadpool-2-thread-2
Inside Indx=202 Inner threadpool-2-thread-3
Inside Indx=102 Inner threadpool-3-thread-3
Inside Indx=104 Inner threadpool-3-thread-5
Inside Indx=103 Inner threadpool-3-thread-4
Inside Indx=203 Inner threadpool-2-thread-4
Inside Indx=204 Inner threadpool-2-thread-5
```

EDIT: As correctly suggested, I have changed my code to !isTerminated() instead of isTerminated() & removing the console output printing inside the while loop. This will ensure that the main thread will not run any statement below the while loop until both Task1 & Task2 are done.

Comment: Re, "...the right approach..." Sometimes, the right approach is whatever works for you. I'd have done differently, but I'm not going to say how, because can't objectively say that my way is any better.

Comment: Your code does not match your prose. You describe Task1 and Task2 as being different, but your code shows them to be the same.

Comment: ya true, basically I wanted to demonstrate how i'm approaching this use case..and my concern was if this is the correct approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a mistake:

```java
executor.shutdown();
        
while(executor.isTerminated()) {
    System.out.println("Terminating Thread-"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

The `while` loop probably is going to do *nothing.* Your tasks have only just been started by the time it calls [`isTerminated()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#isShutdown()). The `isTerminated()` probably will return `false`, and you'll drop out of the loop without ever printing anything.

If you get unlucky, and *all* of the tasks have completed by the time you get to the `isTerminated()` test, then `isTerminated()` will return `true`, *forever,* and your program will get stuck, printing the same message again and again, *forever.*

You probably meant to say, `while(! executor.isTerminated()) {...}`

---

**But Wait!**

There's a better way. You probably don't want those while loops to print again and again *until* the executors shut down either. Instead of *polling* to await the completion of the tasks, why not call [`awaitTermination`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)), and then just print *one* message instead?

```java
executor.shutdown();
try {
    executor.awaitTermination(10000, TimeUnit.DAYS);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    ...handle exception according to the needs of your application...
}   
System.out.println("All tasks completed");}
```

---

This *might* also be a mistake (Only you can say for sure):

```java
System.out.println("Terminating Thread-"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

The message kind of looks as if you expect it to print the name of a thread that it's waiting for. But, what it actually will print is the name of the thread that's doing the waiting. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: I suggest you refer the reader to the boilerplate code for shutdown and await given on the   `ExecutorService` Javadoc. That code covers subtleties not addressed in your code

Comment: correct my bad, I had to change my code to something like this
while(!executor.isTerminated()) {
   // continue untill all opern are done
  }

Comment: Basically I wrote this while loop to understand the life cycle of outer Thread, is it in waiting state until all its inner threads are done with their tasks or what is it?

Comment: @BasilBourque, OK, I have complicated my answer just enough to show that `awaitTermination` throws a checked exception, but I'm not going to add any more than that. Even without the edit, the OP already had accepted my answer, so I guess if it contained enough information to solve their problem, then maybe it can do for others as well. IMO, the other "subtleties" in the javadoc (e.g., forcing the shutdown of recalcitrant tasks) go beyond what the OP asked here.